# How to display the content on product pages without using tabs?

Tags: magento2, tabs, page-content

What's the more elegant way to remove the tabs on the Magento (2.4.2) product page? I'd like to simply show the content without using the tabs.

I was thinking to use some Javascript code in order to "disarm" the tabs widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is how you can remove the Tabs widget in the cleanest way possible.

Basically I took out the blocks from the main block which renders the widget.

This is what I did:

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.detailed" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product info detailed">

                <!-- Description -->
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" as="description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

                <!-- Attributes -->
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info" />

                <!-- Reviews (Anchor) -->
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.review.anchor" template="Magento_Review::anchor.phtml" before="product.info.details" />
                
                <!-- Reviews -->
                <container name="product.info.details" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product reviews wrapper" after="product.attributes">
                    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form" ifconfig="catalog/review/active" after="product_review_list.toolbar">
                        <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="Magento_Review::product/view/list.phtml" ifconfig="catalog/review/active"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar" ifconfig="catalog/review/active"/>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

I also had to recreate the Anchor target link for Reviews since it was included in the block.

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Review/templates/anchor.phtml`

```
<a id="reviews"></a>
```

It seems to work pretty well and, as I said, I think this is the cleanest way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to shift 2 blocks to show content without tab. The first block is description and the another block is product more attributes. In my case i move 2 block from tab section to main product info main area.

In my theme there is layout file Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml file.

I write these 2 lines only.

```
    <move  element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
    <move  element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
```

This code show tab for Review but the description and attributes shifted to product info area. Hope this help you.

Comment: I think better and more elegant approach would be disabling tabs using Javascript.

Comment: Yeah these days JavaScript is best solution to manage frontend. It seems you achieve your goal using javascript. Would you like to share JS answer here.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any blocks in Magento, you can do this from the layout file.

In your `theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
           <referenceBlock name="block.name.to.be.removed" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Replace `block.name.to.be.removed` with the actual block you want to remove.

And you can add this to add any content of your own:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="your.own.content" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/my-own-content.phtml" after="-" />
```

So it becomes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
           <referenceBlock name="block.name.to.be.removed" remove="true" />
           <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="your.own.content" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/my-own-content.phtml" after="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, in your `theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/my-own-content.phtml` file:

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct();
<?php echo $product->getDescription();?>
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE 1**
To add/move other contents from layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
           <referenceBlock name="block.name.to.be.removed" remove="true" />
           <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="your.own.content" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/my-own-content.phtml" after="-" />
           <move element="reviews.tab" destination="your.own.content" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't show the reviews. I also have another tab created by another extension. How can I show them?

Comment: You will have to call them manually in your phtml or move those elements to your block from layout. For ex: `<move element="reviews.tab" destination="your.own.content" after="-"/>`, see my update.

Comment: I think better and more elegant approach would be disabling tabs using Javascript.

Comment: Furthermore, all product reviews are not loaded doing like this.

Comment: The problem is your tab block is removed, so any other module is calling from layout to add their blocks inside the tab, it will not show. You will have to add/move them manually. You will need to find the name of the block and then use `move` tag in your layout to move it to your desired block.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I think that product reviews are loaded using a ajax call once mouse click is done on "Review" title tab. They should be loaded using PHP. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I have used following code to show them:

```
<?php 
  $layout = $block->getLayout();
?>
<div class="product_review"> 
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <?= /* @noEscape */ $layout->renderElement('reviews.tab') ?>
      </div>   
</div>
<div class="product_faqtab"> 
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <?= /* @noEscape */ $layout->renderElement('productfaq.tab') ?>
      </div>   
</div>
<div class="product_care"> 
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <?= /* @noEscape */ $layout->renderElement('productcare.tab') ?>
      </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but how should I use this? Sorry but I didn't get.

Comment: You can show, anywhere on the product page, I have added the additional block below the main image and display content there using the above code.